# Django many-to-many fields and ModelForms

Tags: python, django, forms, django-models, many-to-many

I am now working on a system that is calculating the CO2 emissions of a building. The thresholds are calculated taking into consideration the building type and the area of it. One building can have more building types and each building type has its area which in the end compose the gross area of the building (total area).
What I am trying to do is when the user adds a building for calculation they will add the building information and for each building type the area of the it, the total area of the building is not important for now, but I am thinking on calculating it from the sum of the areas of the building types.

Here is the models.py file:

```
class BuildingType(models.Model):
    type = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    co2_factor = models.DecimalField(max_digits=15, decimal_places=7, blank=True, null=True)


class Building(models.Model):
    bbl = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True, null=True, unique=True)
    area = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)
    electricity = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)
    natural_gas = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)
 
    building_type = models.ManyToManyField(BuildingType, through='BuildingTypeSize', blank=True, null=True)


class BuildingTypeSize(models.Model):
    building = models.ForeignKey(Building, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    building_type = models.ForeignKey(BuildingType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    area = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)
```

I am fairly new to Python and Django, i tried following some tutorials and also the documentation. The way I tried to do it was creating in the forms.py the ModelForm for Building and using the ModelMultipleChoiceField create the selection of the buildingtype. Also, I tried using the custom fields within forms for creating the buulding type selection.

Unfortunately, I can't show what I did because I deleted the previous code.

If you have som resources that will help me figure this out, please do not hesitate to share them.